# How to set the Productverion and Fileversion properties of the executable in PowerBuilder project built with PowerGen

Tags: git, automation, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I'm about to change the Continues Integration build environment for our PowerBuilder application from OrcaScript 11 to PowerGen 8.5 since a full Bootstrap Import seems to be the only solution after having changed source control from TFS to Git.

The application builds but it always results in an executable with the version 1.0.0.1.

In OrcaScript this can be set in the Orca file by adding:

```
set exeinfo property productversion EXE_VER
set exeinfo property fileversion EXE_VER
```

Where EXE_VER is a input parameter sent in through command line:

```
orcascr110.exe /D EXE_VER="10.3.2"
```

But my question now is how this can be done when building with PowerGen 8.5 from E. Crane Computing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier and covers more properties, but it uses a separate app, VersionEdit. It has a GUI, but in your batch file, something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\E. Crane Computing\PowerGen Professional\VECli.exe" %ExeFile% /f=%ProductVer%.%Build%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto veerror
"C:\Program Files\E. Crane Computing\PowerGen Professional\VECli.exe" %ExeFile% /p=%ProductVer%.%Build%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto veerror
"C:\Program Files\E. Crane Computing\PowerGen Professional\VECli.exe" %ExeFile% /sa=Release,%ProductVer%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto veerror
"C:\Program Files\E. Crane Computing\PowerGen Professional\VECli.exe" %ExeFile% /sa=Build,%Build%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto veerror
```

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks Terry, just was I was looking for.

Comment: Two warnings on alternatives: 1. I've heard from reliable sources I trust (e.g. Sybase technical staff) that PowerBuilder EXEs are not standard Windows EXEs, so use of tools for standards Windows EXEs like version stampers are at your own risk, and 2) standard tools don't stamp PBDs, AFAIK. I dunno; might be worth trying.